# Why won't my content.js script communicate with my background.js script (chrome extensions)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a basic extension in google chrome which includes a content and background script. For some reason, when a new tab is created and i try to send a message from my background script to the content script, the event listener in `content.js` is not receiving the message. I can't see any `console.log` in the new tabs dev tools. Can anyone explain where i am going wrong?

content.js:

```
//listen to background.js
/* global chrome */


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    console.log("message received")
    const el = document.createElement('injected');
    el.id = "injected-element"
    el.innerHTML = `<div> this has been injected </div>`
    document.body.appendChild(el)
    sendResponse({ "message":"sent from content script" });
  }
);

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count +1 });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Extension installed successfully")
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
    tab.id,
    {"message":"hello from background script"}
  );
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Article Scorer",
  "author": "Sean Barker",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "icons": {
    "192": "logo192.png",
    "512": "logo512.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The answer below explains what happens. As for a solution, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably because when the `onCreated` listener is triggered, it attempts to send the message back to the tab, but `content.js` has not been loaded yet since new tabs by default do not have a url, and your manifest declares that the content script will be injected when it matches `"<all_urls>"`. `content.js` is only loaded once the new tab is directed to some site.

To see this happening you can do the following:

1. Place a breakpoint in the `onCreated` listener in `background.js`.
2. Open a new tab (breakpoint will get hit)
3. In the new tab, navigate to some site
4. Open dev tools and see `content.js` is loaded
5. Unbreak and continue exection in `background.js`
6. You'll see "message received" printed in the console.

In effect, your background script is sending the message properly, but nothing is listening.

Comment: which breakpoint type shall i use? I'm not sure which one to check inside the list under event listeners